# Show that $4\mathbb{Z}+6\mathbb{Z}=2\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Show that $4\mathbb{Z}+6\mathbb{Z}=2\mathbb{Z}$.

My attempt goes something like this:

An arbitrary elt in $4\mathbb{Z}$ looks something like $4x$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

An arbitrary elt in $6\mathbb{Z}$ looks something like $6x$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Then $4x+6y=2(2x+3y)$, note $(2x+3y) \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is the form of an element in $2\mathbb{Z}$.

Thus $4\mathbb{Z}+6\mathbb{Z}=2\mathbb{Z}$

Would this be correct? It seems too easy. Should I have used the fact that for ideals I and J, I+J is an ideal? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is an **elt**?

Comment: You must show that every element of $2\mathbb{Z}$ can be obtained as the sum of an element from $4\mathbb{Z}$ and and element from $6\mathbb{Z}$; you must also show that no element not in $2\mathbb{Z}$ can be so obtained (equivalently, that the *only* numbers so obtained are in $2\mathbb{Z}$).  Thus far you've only done the latter.

Comment: @Bernard From context, an abbreviation for "element".

Comment: @lulu: Good point, though I think that's just carelessness in editing.  OP should correct as "An arbitrary element in $6\mathbb{Z}$ looks something like $6y$ for some $y \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then $4x+6y = 2(2x+3y)$; note that $2x+3y \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $2(2x+3y) \in 2\mathbb{Z}$."

Comment: OP: If you use your last adduced fact, you must still show that $2$ is an element in the ideal sum.

Comment: @DuncanRamage: I guessed, but I wanted to point it's somewhat irksome to read this SMS-like language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is too easy! You've only shown one direction of the set inequality, that $4\mathbb{Z} + 6\mathbb{Z} \subseteq 2\mathbb{Z}$. Now you need to go the other direction, show that any even integer can be decomposed appropriately.

Hint: 2 = 6 - 4.

Answer (score 3):

You can show more generally that $a\mathbb{Z} +b\mathbb{Z} =\text{gcd} (a,b) \mathbb{Z} $.

Answer (score 0):

You have shown that $4\mathbb{Z} +6\mathbb{Z} \subseteq 2\mathbb{Z}$. You should show that you have inclusion the other direction as well, so $2\mathbb{Z} \subseteq 4\mathbb{Z} +6\mathbb{Z}$.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'too easy'. A more complicated proof does not mean that it's better, although if it helps you understand the connections between ideas it might be helpful to you personally.